how to make data more valuable for training process

i have this dataset which i wanna manupilate to do some analysis for a school project
However the correlation matrix didnt show me a good result because there is no important numeric data

Thats why i wanted to convert the categorial data like indicator and indicator_topic to numbers but they have arround 50 possible values each .
I tries the One-hot encoding but now the data seems to be unmanageble.
Can some one help me find a better way to make the data more clear for the training process.
Sorry im a beginner so can anyone tell me whats the best variable in the dataset to apply training on .
Thanks
